# Python: ImportError: No module named connector

Tags: python, python-2.7, module

When I execute a Python script I receive:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/.../Documents/development/python/migrate_upper.py", line 3, in <module>
    import mysql.connector
ImportError: No module named connector
```

I am executing like that:

```
$ python migrate_upper.py
```

It worked 1 month ago, I haven't worked with Python since then. I spent 2 hours trying to understand what is wrong but I got lost with `PYTHONPATH`, `pip` and other hints.

However when I send the script to Python shell:

```
$ python < migrate_upper.py
```

everything works. I think that this is not the proper way to execute python scripts. How can I get the script working without the Python shell?

Comment: What other files do you have in `.../development/python/`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it with the help of Ethan's comment.
I had a folder mysql beneath ../development/python. I can't remember why I put it there. I guess python tried to import that folder instead of ../site-packages/mysql.